# How do I get my dogs to not attack my friend when we hit each other?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Me and my cousin like to punch each other to annoy each other. but whenever we do, our dogs attack us, even if they are sitting. How can I make it so they don't?

There are no commands on Xbox 360 edition.

Answer (score 1):

Without commands or mods it’s not possible unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

[@Sam Hill](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/247391/sam-hill) is correct, this is not possible. But you can trap your wolves in an inescapable area so that they can't run to get you when they try to move around.